# Suggest category for a piece of text

Tags: python

I've been searching for a opensource solution to suggest a category given a question or text.

For example, "who is Lady Gaga?" would probably return 'Entertainment', 'Music', or 'Celebrity'.

"How many strike out there are for baseball?" would give me 'Baseball', or 'Sport'.

The categorization doesn't have to be perfect but should be some what close.

Also is there anywhere I can get a list of popular categories?

Answer (score 3):

This is a [document classification problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_classification) - your "document" is simply the query or text.

You'll first need to decide what the list of possible categories is. "Who is Lady Gaga?" could be Entertainment, Celebrity, Questions-In-English, Biography, People, etc. Next you'll apply a decision framework to assign a score for each category to the text. The highest score is its category - as long as it's above a noise threshold and there isn't a second-place category that's too close to differentiate. Decision frameworks can include approaches like a Bayesian network or a set of custom rules.

Some open source projects that implement classifiers include:

- [Classifier4J](http://sourceforge.net/projects/classifier4j/)
- [Matlab Classification Toolbox](http://sourceforge.net/projects/classification/)
- [POPFile](http://sourceforge.net/projects/popfile/) (for email)
- [OpenNLP Maximum Entropy Package](http://sourceforge.net/projects/maxent/)

Answer (score 1):

Screen scrape Wolfram alpha.

- http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Who+is+lady+gaga
- http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=What+is+baseball

You can probably get a good list of categories from [dmoz](http://www.dmoz.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Not much of an answer, but perhaps this categorized dictionary would help:

http://www.provalisresearch.com/wordstat/WordNet.html

I imagine you could extract the uncommon words from the string, look them up in the categorized dictionary, and return the categories that get the most matches on your terms. It'll be tricky to deal with pop culture references like "Lady Gaga", though...maybe you could do a Google search and analyze the results of that.

Answer (score 0):

Others have done quite a bit of work on your behalf, so I'd suggest just using something like the [OpenCalais API](http://www.opencalais.com/APIkey). There's a python wrapper to the API at http://code.google.com/p/python-calais/.

"Who is Lady Gaga?" seems to be too short a piece of text for them to give a decent response. However, if you took the trouble to do a two step process and grab the first paragraph from wikipedia for Lady Gaga, and then supply that to the OpenCalais API you get very good results.

You can check it out quickly by just cut and pasting the first paragraph from wikipedia into the [OpenCalais viewer](http://viewer.opencalais.com/). The result is a classification into the topic "Entertainment Culture" with a 100% confidence estimate.

Similarly, the baseball example returns "sports" as the topic with further social tags of "recreation", "baseball" etc.

**Edit** Here's another thought prompted by Calais' use of social tags: sending the wikipedia url for Lady Gaga to the delicious API with

```
curl -k https://user:password@api.del.icio.us/v1/posts/suggest?url=http://en
.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lady_gaga
```

returns
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <suggest>
  <recommended>music</recommended>
  <recommended>wikipedia</recommended>
  <recommended>wiki</recommended>
  <recommended>people</recommended>
  <recommended>bio</recommended>
  <recommended>cool</recommended>
  <recommended>facts</recommended>
  <popular>music</popular>
  <popular>gaga</popular>
  <popular>ladygaga</popular>
  <popular>wikipedia</popular>
  <popular>lady</popular>`

etc. Should be easy enough to ignore the wikipedia/wiki type entries.